# asgiref.sync_to_async doesn't propagates inner exceptions properly

Tags: python-asyncio, asgi

When using `sync_to_async` inside an async block (like the following code), the exception is printed only on exit (after 10 seconds, when loop is shutting down)

```py
import asyncio
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async


def f():
    1 / 0


async def test():
    print('start')
    await sync_to_async(f)()
    print('stop')

asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(test())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(10))
```

The same code using `ThreadPoolExecutor` prints stack-trace immediately:

```py
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor

def f():
    1 / 0

async def test():
    print('start')
    await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(executor, f)
    print('stop')

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(8)
asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(test())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(10))
```

(tested with Python 3.9.16 and 3.10.9 on linux)

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's a garbage-collection issue. The exception is propagated correctly (and can be caught with `try/except` block). But unhandled exceptions in async task is only printed on the when task is garbage collected.

Calling the `gc.collect` explicitly garbage collects the task, and prints it's unhandled exception:

```py
import asyncio
import gc
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

def f():
    1 / 0

async def test():
    print('start')
    await sync_to_async(f)()
    print('stop')

async def sleep():
    for i in range(10):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        gc.collect()

asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(test())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(sleep())
```

Comment: manual garbage collection is a hack, and un-needed in this case. If you care abut exceptions happening in code you are awaiting, use one of asyncio.TaskGroup. asyncio.gather or asyncio.wait instead of simply awaiting task completion: when the task is 'done" (due to raising)  you get to check the results and inspect the exception in the proper attributes for that.